# How to calculate the bit error rate of flush+reload on RSA

Tags: security, caching, rsa, hardware, side-channel-attacks

I am learning to utilize flush+reload method to get private key of RSA.
I read related papers
[flush+reload](https://scholar.google.com.hk/scholar?hl=zh-CN&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=FLUSH%2B+RELOAD%3A+A+high+resolution%2C+low+noise%2C+L3+cache+side-channel+attack&btnG=)  and found its open source code ([flush+reloa](https://github.com/defuse/flush-reload-attacks) [flush+reloa](https://github.com/DanGe42/flush-reload)).
And I experimented according to the tutorial.

I am very grateful for these open source codes.
But with these open source codes, I always have a very confusing question. It's just that they don't introduce what the correct result looks like (if I know the correct result, I can reproduce them faster, and better observe the impact of the paper's idea on the experiment).

For example, the experiment of Flush+Reload on RSA. The bottom image presents an optimized RSA implementation, known as CRT-RSA.

According to the introduction of the paper, as long as the Square-Reduce-Multiply in the encryption process is detected, the private key can also be restored.

The paper states:

> Square-Reduce-Multiply-Reduce indicate a set bit. Sequences of
> Square-Reduce which are not followed by Multiply indicate a clear bit.

But according to the previous description this seems to restore `dp` and `dq`. Because the above code is calculating `mp = c^dp mod p` and `mq = c^dq mod q`.

The paper states:

> Hence, knowing dp (and, symmetrically, dq) is sufficient for factoring
> n and breaking the encryption

By reading the paper and source code, I found that he always checks whether the following three cache lines are used when decrypting.

```
 probe 0x080f7607 S #mpih-mul.c:270 (First cache line in mpih_sqr_n())
    probe 0x080f6c45 r #mpih-div.c:329 (Loop in default case in mpihelp_divrem())
    probe 0x080f6fa8 M #mpih-mul.c:121 (First cache line of mul_n())
```

After that, the author directly gave the bit error rate.
This feels suspicious. I measured the access latency of the three cache lines above during decryption. And restore them to `01` bits according to the following introduction.

> Square-Reduce-Multiply-Reduce indicate a set bit. Sequences of
> Square-Reduce which are not followed by Multiply indicate a clear bit.

How can I calculate the bit error rate? Does this restore dp or dq? or something else?
How to get the correct dp and dq for comparison?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I think the most important tag for this would be [cryptography], you might want to replace [hardware] maybe (I'm not sure you want to, so I didn't). Also this touches so lightly on software development that I think this might be more suitable for [Crypto SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

#### What they leak

I don't know which example specifically you are talking about.
If you clarify this (e.g., by adding a link) I may be able to edit this and provide a better answer.

When attacking RSA, it is usually assumed that `N` and `e` (the public modulus and exponent) are known. 
To break RSA, we need to recover the private exponent `d`. 
However, there are multiple ways to reconstruct `d`: 
Since `N = p * q`, leaking either `p` or `q` will trivially recover `p = N / q` (or `q = N / p` respectively). 
Knowing `p` and `q`, we can calculate `d = e^(-1) mod phi(N)` (where `phi(N) = (p-1) * (q-1)`). 
Of course, leaking `d` itself will also suffice. 
To break CRT-RSA, leaking either `dq` or `dp` can be used to calculate one of the primes `p` or `q`, thus recovering `d`.

#### Bit Error Rate

To get the bit error rate, you have to know the correct result, then you calculate it the following way:

```
number of incorrectly leaked bits / total bits of the secret
```

For example, if I leak the bits `10001`, but the correct key is `10101`, the bit error rate is:

```
1 / 5 = 20%
```

Since one of the leaked bits is incorrect.

Comment: thank you! But I don't know if the above method detects dp or dq? And is there a command or website that can decompose the RSA private key directly into dp or dq?

Comment: If you know p and q (as well as the public key component e and n), you can calculate d = e^(-1) mod (p-1)*(q-1) and then dp = d mod (p - 1)  (and dq respectively)